# Using collapsed navbar as default in Bootstrap3

Tags: navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way of using the collapsed version of the navbar for all versions of the site regardless of the size?

Have been changing the following but not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing this:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
    }
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 15px;
      padding: 9px 10px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      display: block;
      width: 22px;
      height: 2px;
      border-radius: 1px;
    }
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
    margin-top: 4px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply set the `@grid-float-breakpoint` Less variable (which lives in `bootstrap/less/variables.less`) to an absurdly high value (e.g. `999999999px`) and then recompile Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS override could be simplified to this:

```
.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.collapse.in{
  display:block !important;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/nANH5ownG9